# ROC curves look different using pROC

Tags: r

I am new to using ROC curves for analysis and I still learning how to perform data analysis in R. I am using the wine quality data from the UCI repository for binary classification.

I am using the `pROC` package in R to compute the AUC and plot the ROC curves.

The SVM ROC curve that I get only has 3 three points. When I looked at the summary  it says that only 3 thresholds are used.
    For the SVM analysis I am using the following code:

```
svm_fit = svm(wine2.lowHigh ~  fixed.acidity+ volatile.acidity+ citric.acid + residual.sugar +
    chlorides + free.sulfur.dioxide +total.sulfur.dioxide+density + pH +
    sulphates + alcohol,data=training,kernel="linear", scale=FALSE,probability = TRUE)

probs_svm = predict(svm_fit,testing)
my_svm <-roc(testing$wine2.lowHigh~as.numeric(probs_svm)) 
plot(my_svm)
```

The Logistic regression curve that has 51 thresholds according to the summary.
The code that I use for the logistic regression is the following:

```
lr_fit = glm(wine2.lowHigh ~  fixed.acidity+ volatile.acidity+ citric.acid + residual.sugar +
    chlorides + free.sulfur.dioxide +total.sulfur.dioxide+density + pH +
    sulphates + alcohol,data=training,family = binomial)
probs_lr = predict(lr_fit,testing[1:11],type = "response")
my_lr <-roc(testing$wine2.lowHigh~probs_lr)
plot(my_lr)
```

When I compare the SVM ROC curve to the Logistic regression curve, the curves look different.

My question is why do the curves look different. The SVM curve is smooth and Logistic Regression curve is jagged. I also used `unique()` and found that the SVM analysis returned some of the same probabilities while the Logistic Regression had different probabilities could this be why?

The dataset is from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine+Quality. It is the white wine quality dataset. The response was split into high and low for binary classification based on the scale that it was measured on.

[image: ROC curves of Logistic regression and SVM]

Comment: please add the data to make your question reproducible